# Extract cell value based on multiple criteria without using index and match formulas?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have two workbooks and need to extract data from one into the other. The one with the data looks like this:

```
BE | Account | Site | Major | Sub | Description | Beginning | Ending
02 | 00-345  | 103  | 23    | 12  | Some thing  | $125,000  | $98800
02 | 00-345  | 113  | 23    | 11  | Irrelevant  | $120,000  | $10700
02 | 00-345  | 103  | 22    | 12  | Some thing  | $180,060  | $90000
02 | 00-345  | 113  | 22    | 09  | Irrelevant  | $177,435  | $93400
78 | 00-345  | 222  | 12    | 12  | Some thing  | $129,800  | $40000
78 | 00-345  | 111  | 23    | 12  | Irrelevant  | $620,509  | $90066
78 | 00-345  | 504  | 23    | 12  | Some thing  | $99,000   | $90470
98 | 00-345  | 177  | 23    | 12  | Irrelevant  | $900,000  | $10304
98 | 00-345  | 509  | 23    | 12  | Some thing  | $180,164  | $12904
```

What I need to do is extract the Value from the "ending" column based on the matching BE, Major, and Sub. For example, given BE: 02, Major: 22, Sub: 12 I would want the cell to return the value $90000. Is there a way to do this without using a lengthy Index/match formula? Perhaps through the use of some level of filtering or pivot tables? I can't seem to get past a formula approach but want to avoid the use of a ridiculously long formula if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is numbers, and if the combination of those three are unique as in your example you can use SUMIFS():

```
=SUMIFS(H:H,A:A,2,D:D,22,E:E,12)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works great. So much better than the messy, complex plan I was concocting in my head.